# Wrong way to Add Product to Cart with Custom Price

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1

I am adding product to cart with custom price but It doesn't work with multiple currency on store.

Currency symbol is changed but currency not converting in selected currency on cart, checkout, minicart.

```
//script to add product to cart with custom price
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
$item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
$price = 100; //set your price here
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Not work in magento 1 and magento 2.

Here is reply from Magento community:
"custom price is using only in Admin area when we reorder or edit an order. In that case we can change price item and set a custom price. The currency would not be changed and stayed as it was when the order had been placed." and said that the way I am following to add product with custom price is wrong.

So Is there any correct way to add product in cart with custom price in fly?

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks for your help but It doesn't make any difference.